# updating of the cholesky decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

I try cholrank1 update ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Updating_the_decomposition)) of the symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrix .

```
function [L] = cholupdate(L,x)
    p = length(x);
    for k=1:p
        r = sqrt(L(k,k)^2 + x(k)^2);
        c = r / L(k, k);
        s = x(k) / L(k, k);
        L(k, k) = r;
        L(k+1:p,k) = (L(k+1:p,k) + s*x(k+1:p)) / c;
        x(k+1:p) = c*x(k+1:p) - s*L(k+1:p,k);
    end
end
```

Get SPD matrix and factorize it:

```
H = J'*J
L = chol(H)';
L_updated = cholupdate(L, new_J_row');
```

It works well. But how can I modify algorithm when I need to do normalization of the SPD matrix?

```
% normalization
n = 1 ./ sqrt(diag(H));
Hn = diag(n) * H * diag(n);
Ln = chol(Hn)';

Ln_updated = ???
```

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to get. Can you elaborate?

Comment: For clarification, you just want the Cholesky factor of $D(H + uu^T)D$ for a vector $u$ and a diagonal matrix $D$?

Comment: @user251257 Yes. But I want to make an _update_ of existing factor of D*H*D. Not the refactor the whole matrix, just modified elemetns

Comment: Update with $v=Du$?

Comment: @user251257 I have computed chol(D*H*D). I want to update it to obtain chol(D*(H+u*u')*D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the cholesky decomposition $LL^T = DHD$ for some positive definite diagonal matrix $D$, another positive definite diagonal matrix $\tilde D$ and a vector $u$. You can compute the decomposition 
$$\tilde L \tilde L^T = \tilde D (H+uu^T) \tilde D = \tilde D H\tilde D + (\tilde D u)(\tilde D u)^T$$
as follow:

1. Let $\bar L = \tilde D D^{-1} L$, which gives $\bar L \bar L = \tilde D H \tilde D$.
2. Update $\bar L$ to $\tilde L$.

Comment: Sorry, but what is "v"? Where is "v" used?

Comment: $v$ is just a name. update with the vector $Du$.

Comment: Please look at my first post

"n = 1 ./ sqrt(diag(H));
Hn = diag(n) * H * diag(n);
Ln = chol(Hn)';"

I have factor of D*H*D. And I need to update it with u'u. But adding "u'u" leads to change matrix D (normalization matrix). And I have to take it.

Comment: For clarification, you have the factor of $DHD$ and want the factor of $\tilde D(H+uu^T) \tilde D$, where $D$ is `diag(1./sqrt(diag(H)))` and $\tilde D$ is `diag(1./sqrt(diag(H + u*u')))`?

Comment: @user1312837: Regarding last comment: If the answer is yes, notice that $\tilde DH\tilde D = \tilde D D^{-1} (DHD) D^{-1} \tilde D$.

Comment: Answer is "yes".